# Detect poor performance with CSS3 features

Tags: performance, css, media-queries

It's obvious that using CSS3 shadows, tranparency, effects and other features can dramatically lower overall page performance on some phones/tablets, but I can't find out a single way to determine if device performance is not enough to handle "heavy" CSS3 features. I'd create two versions of CSS: lite for budget phones/tablets and full for PCs and so on; but how should I choose? Using media queries doesn't look like a moderate option.

Comment: This question is either **too broad**, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a sophisticated topic and hard to answer correctly without epics. I try to keep it short and simple:

### Tooling

Chrome Dev Tools offer many convenient features for profiling JS and CSS Features. As a first step I'd recommend the Timeline, activating the Capturing of 'JS Profile', `Memory` and `Paint` and then analyse the largest colored blocks (where a lot of calcuations/layouting/painting needed to be done. More detailled information: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

### How to (CSS performance focused)

A quite popular misconception is the rumour of "long and a high amount of selectors" cause Perf. Issues. From what I've seen, debugged and read by great performance Pros like [Paul Lewis](https://aerotwist.com/), this is usually NOT the bottleneck. Computing and applying CSS values is extremely fast. Instead Painting and Layouting, especially when using animations is costly. There are tricks like using `translate` instead of left/top positioning, using the `will-change` property and many more. You may find an overview about what causes what here: https://csstriggers.com/

Conclusion: Media Queries might not be a perfect solution, but not bad either, as the huge amount of selectors probably won't matter.

Comment: Oh, thanks. This CSS Triggers information looks very useful. I'll check it out and make some optimisations based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to chose by screen resolution? Budget devices are almost always with bad screens :)

Comment: Yeah, I think about this too. But I assume it'll be quite inaccurate because, you know, there are portrait/landscape orientaions, different PPI values and so on. For example, my Lumia 525 screen is 800px width, but performance is poor, however I don't think that cut off effects on any <800px device will be a right decision.

Comment: If you are familiar with PHP, you can also use something like this tool to detect devices in details - http://mobiledetect.net/